# How do the stages of insight before stream entry relate to the suttas

Tags: sutras, vipassana, visuddhimagga

Are the stages of knowledge before stream entry mentioned in the suttas? How does this correlate with the Visuddhimagga? E.g. sabba-kaya-patisamvedi (in some interpretations) may directly relate to bhanga-ñāṇa.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The sixteen stages of knowledge are taken for the most part from the *Patisambhidamagga*, a treatise attributed to Sariputta. They are also enumerated in the *Abhidhammatthasangaha*. Some are specifically mentioned in the suttas, e.g.:

**udayabbaya**

> Yo ca vassasataṃ jīve apassaṃ udayabbayaṃ
>
> Ekāhaṃ jīvitaṃ seyyo passato udayabbayaṃ.
>
> Dhp. 113

**nibbida**

> Sabbe saṅkhārā aniccā'ti yadā paññāya passati
>
> Atha nibbindati dukkhe esa maggo visuddhiyā.
>
> Dhp. 277

**ādīnava**

> Disvā ādīnavaṃ loke ñatvā dhammaṃ nirūpadhiṃ,
>
> Ariyo na ramatī pāpe pāpe na ramatī suci.
>
> Ud. 5.6

The knowledges are also closely related to the seven visuddhis from the Rathavinita Sutta (MN 24), again attributed to Sariputta (and Punna Mantaniputta).

Answer (score 1):

[Into the Stream](http://www.accesstoinsight.org/lib/study/into_the_stream.html) is A Study Guide on the First Stage of Awakening by Thanissaro Bhikkhu

The contents include:

1. The Way to Stream Entry

   - Introduction

     > The practices leading to stream entry are encapsulated in four factors:
     >
     > > 1. Association with people of integrity is a factor for stream-entry.
     > > 2. Listening to the true Dhamma is a factor for stream-entry.
     > > 3. Appropriate attention is a factor for stream-entry.
     > > 4. Practice in accordance with the Dhamma is a factor for stream-entry.
   - Association with People of Integrity

     > As he was seated to one side, Ven. Ananda said to the Blessed One, "This is half of the holy life, lord: having admirable people as friends, companions, & colleagues."
     >
     > "Don't say that, Ananda. Don't say that. Having admirable people as friends, companions, & colleagues is actually the whole of the holy life. When a monk has admirable people as friends, companions, & colleagues, he can be expected to develop & pursue the noble eightfold path.
   - Listening to the True Dhamma

     > "There are these five rewards in listening to the Dhamma. Which five?
     >
     > "[1] One hears what one has not heard before. [2] One clarifies what one has heard before. [3] One gets rid of doubt. [4] One's views are made straight. [5] One's mind grows serene.
     >
     > "These are the five rewards in listening to the Dhamma."
   - Appropriate Attention

     > With regard to internal factors, I don't envision any other single factor like appropriate attention as doing so much for a monk in training, who has not attained the goal but remains intent on the unsurpassed safety from bondage. A monk who attends appropriately abandons what is unskillful and develops what is skillful.
   - Practice in Accordance with the Dhamma

     > this is what accords with the Dhamma: that he keep cultivating disenchantment with regard to form, that he keep cultivating disenchantment with regard to feeling, that he keep cultivating disenchantment with regard to perception, that he keep cultivating disenchantment with regard to fabrications, that he keep cultivating disenchantment with regard to consciousness. As he keeps cultivating disenchantment with regard to form... feeling... perception... fabrications... consciousness, he comprehends form... feeling... perception... fabrications... consciousness. As he comprehends form... feeling... perception... fabrications... consciousness, he is totally released from form... feeling... perception... fabrications... consciousness. He is totally released from sorrows, lamentations, pains, distresses, & despairs. He is totally released, I tell you, from suffering & stress."
2. Stream Entry & Its Results

   - Introduction
   - The Arising of the Dhamma Eye
   - The Three Fetters
   - The Character of a Stream-enterer
   - Rewards
   - Advice

If you look at the study guide Thanissaro Bhikkhu links each sutta.

Comment: Good answer but tangential to the relationship between Vidarshana Nana as per Vissudimagga and the Suttas. Up voted but not accepting it.